# the background of the submenu does not take up all the space

Tags: css

In my sidebar, when I hover over a submenu (portfolio or contact)

[image]

I would like the red background to take up the entire background of the cell.

[image]

Do you know how I could create this?

I think the problem is here? But I don't see what priority I should add?

```
.sidebar .nav-links li:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

Thanks a lot

Here is a demonstration via [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/kora1348/exemple1?file=src/styles.css)

***HTML***

```
<ul class="nav-links" id="nav-links" >
   <li *ngFor="let item of menuSidebar" #itemEl >
      <div *ngIf="item.sub_menu.length > 0" class="dropdown-title" (click)="showSubmenu(itemEl)">
      <a>
      <i [class]="item.icon"></i>
      <span class="link_name">{{item.link_name}}</span>
      </a>
      <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down arrow'></i>
      </div>
      <ul class="sub-menu" [class.blank]="item.sub_menu.length == 0">
         <li><a class="link_name">{{item.link_name}}</a></li>
         <li *ngFor="let item_sub of item.sub_menu" routerLinkActive="active">
            <a [routerLink]="[item_sub.link]">{{item_sub.link_name}}</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

***CSS***

```
/* Sidebar */
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 260px;
  background: white;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close {
  width: 60px;

}

.sidebar .logo-details{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.sidebar .logo-details img{
  height: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
 
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .logo-details img {
  width: 37px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-3px);
}

.sidebar .nav-links {
  height: 100%;
  width: 260px;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar .nav-links::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links > li {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li:hover {
  background: red;
}


/* Dropdown Title */
.sidebar .nav-links .dropdown-title {
  width: 260px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.52s ease;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links .dropdown-title {
  width: 60px;
}


.sidebar .nav-links li i {
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #ffa726;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li:hover i, 
.sidebar .nav-links li.active i {
  color: white;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu i.arrow {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

/* a Tag */
.sidebar .nav-links li a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Link Name */
.sidebar .nav-links li a .link_name {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #ffa726;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li:hover a .link_name, 
.sidebar .nav-links li.active a .link_name {
  color: white;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li a .link_name {
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* Sub Menu */
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu {
  padding: 6px 6px 14px 50px;
  background: #239CD3;
  display: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu a {
  color: #ffa726;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 7px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu li {
  padding-left: 10px;
}


.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu li:hover a, 
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu li.active a {
  color: black;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li .sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: -10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li .sub-menu li {
  padding: 6px 15px;
  width: 200px;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li:hover .sub-menu {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu .link_name {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li .sub-menu .link_name {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: block;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li .sub-menu li:first-child {
  background: white;
  pointer-events: none;
}


.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu.blank {
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li:hover .sub-menu.blank, 
.sidebar .nav-links li.active .sub-menu.blank {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close ~ .home-section {
  left: 60px;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the behaviour stems from the parent `.sub-menu` padding. You change background color of the child `li` element that is pushed away by the padding.

You can remove the padding from `.sub-menu` container and add it to your list items accordingly (if it's required by design):

```
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu li:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 6px 6px 0 50px;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu li:last-child {
    padding: 0 6px 14px 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a `padding` on your `.sub-menu` class. Removing it should solve your problem:

```
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu {
  background: #239CD3;
  display: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

Check out the [box model](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) to better understand the behaviour of [padding](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp).